# ASP.NET using embedded resources in Bundling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, embedded-resource, bundling-and-minification, virtualpathprovider

I'm trying to implement a generic approach for providing the possibility for different assemblies in my web solution to use embedded JavaScript and CSS files from embedded resources. [This blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/asp-net-bundling-and-minification-and-embedded-resources) shows a technique using a VirtualPathProvider. This works fine, but the VirtualPathProvider needs to be included in each assembly containing embedded resources.

I tried to enhance the VirtualPathProvider from the blog post, so that an assembly can be passed into it and it loads the resource from its assembly:

```
public EmbeddedVirtualPathProvider(VirtualPathProvider previous, Assembly assembly)
{
    this.previous = previous;
    this.assembly = assembly;
}
```

On initialization it reads all embedded resources from the passed assembly:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();

    this.assemblyResourceNames = this.assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    this.assemblyName = this.assembly.GetName().Name;
}
```

And the `GetFile`reads the content from the passed assembly:

```
public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
{
    if (IsEmbeddedPath(virtualPath))
    {
        if (virtualPath.StartsWith("~", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            virtualPath = virtualPath.Substring(1);
        }

        if (!virtualPath.StartsWith("/", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            virtualPath = string.Concat("/", virtualPath);
        }

        var resourceName = string.Concat(this.assembly.GetName().Name, virtualPath.Replace("/", "."));
        var stream = this.assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

        if (stream != null)
        {
            return new EmbeddedVirtualFile(virtualPath, stream);
        }
        else
        {
            return _previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }
    }
    else
        return _previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
}
```

Checking if resource is an embedded resource of this assembly is by checking the resource names read in the `Initialize` method:

```
private bool IsEmbeddedPath(string path)
{
    var resourceName = string.Concat(this.assemblyName, path.TrimStart('~').Replace("/", "."));
    return this.assemblyResourceNames.Contains(resourceName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

I moved the `EmbeddedVirtualPathProvider` class to the main web project (ProjectA), so that it doesn't need to be included in each assembly containing embedded resources and registered it using the following code in `Global.asax`:

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(
    new EmbeddedVirtualPathProvider(
        HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider,
        typeof(ProjectB.SomeType).Assembly));
```

In the project containing the embedded resources (ProjectB) I still create the following bundle in a `PostApplicationStartMethod`:

```
 BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Embedded/Js")
     .Include("~/Scripts/SomeFolder/MyScript.js")
 );
```

`Scripts/MyScript.js` is the embedded resource in ProjectB.

With this I receive the following exception:

> Directory 'C:\webs\ProjectA\Scripts\SomeFolder\' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.

**Update**
Full stack trace available in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/pascalberger/e1c84c8d8bb966cbe666).

**Update**
Also the VirtualPathProvider itself seems to work fine. If I load the file directly and not through the bundle and set the following entry in the `web.config` it loads the embedded javascript from ProjectB:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="MyStaticFileHandler" path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Where is your Startup class?In ProjectA or in ProjectB?

Comment: ProjectA is a NuGet Package containing the VirtualPathProvider. ProjectB another NuGet Package providing some functionality with views (there are multiple of it). The NuGet Package ProjectB has a dependency on the NuGetPackage ProjectA. Applications install the ProjectB NuGetPackages.

Therefore Startup is outside of ProjectA and ProjectB, but ProjectA and ProjectB can hook into PreApplicationStartMethod.

Comment: It seems that `IsEmbeddedPath` method return `false` whereas it should return `true`. Could you tell us the value of `path` and `resourceName` before the error occured ?

Comment: If I debug `IsEmbeddedPath` returns `true` and `GetFile` is also called and returns the stream of the embedded resource.

Comment: @PascalBerger `IsEmbeddedPath` always return `true`. By looking at the call stack, we can see that `GetCacheDependency` is called and then the base `GetCacheDependency` is called which means that `IsEmbeddedPath` return `false` one time.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint in `FileExists` with a condition of `virtualPath.Contains("MyScript.js")`, if it is called `virtualPath` is set to `~/Scripts/SomeFolder/MyScript.js`. In `IsEmbeddedPath` the resourceName is `ProjectA.SomeFolder.MyScript.js` which exists in `assemblyResourceNames` and therefore `true` is returned.

I've also another breakpoint with the same condition set in `GetFile` which is called afterwards. And the `VirtualFile` object for the resource is returned from there.

Afterwards no further calls to either `FileExists` or `GetFile` happen

Comment: @CyrilDurand The VirtualPathProvider itself seems to work fine (see updated question). If I directly load the JS file, don't use a bundle, and declare all *.js files as static files it finds the embedded JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ASP.net optimization create the bundle it call `GetCacheDependency` for the virtual directory of the script. Your `GetCacheDependency` implementation only check virtual file, for virtual directory it relies on the base `VirtualPathProvider` which check if directory exists and failed.

To solve this issue, you have to check if the path is a *directory* of one of your script and return null for the `GetCacheDependency`.

To safely determine if `virtualPath` is a bundle directory, you can use the  `BundleTable.Bundles` collection or using a convention (ie: every bundle should starts with ~/Embedded).

```
public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(
    string virtualPath, 
    IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, 
    DateTime utcStart)
{
    // if(virtualPath.StartsWith("~/Embedded"))
    if(BundleTables.Bundles.Any(b => b.Path == virtualPath))
    {
        return null; 
    }
    if (this.IsEmbeddedPath(virtualPath))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return this._previous
                   .GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but `GetCacheDependency` is not called for `C:\webs\ProjectA\Scripts\SomeFolder\` only for `~/Embedded/Js`.

Comment: @PascalBerger When the exception occurs what is the value of `virtualPath` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Was an error in my file/path detection. If I fix check for `~/Embedded/Js` and return `null` it works. Now I need to only find a safe way to determine if `virtualPath` is a directory or file :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding below error

Directory 'C:\webs\ProjectA\Scripts\SomeFolder\' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.

This happens specifically if all resource files of the SomeFolder are embedded and thus in published site - it does not have this folder created.

In case of bundle - it keeps timestamp when the bundle is created and it monitors the folder for any file change to trigger update in the bundle file.

Here - no files in the SomeFolder to monitor - as all are embedded. Didn't find to prevent the folder monitoring - but by handling this specific exception, it can be ignored.